# End points in Flask Admin using different fields than ID

Tags: flask-admin

I've got an Order object where the edit screen for an Order object with ID of 5 looks something like this: /admin/order/edit/?id=8&url=%2Fadmin%2Forder%2F

If I've got a field on the Order object called invoice, is there a way to use a URL end point for the edit screen using the invoice field?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, using **column_extra_row_actions** you can create an action that accepts **row_id** (Order.ID in your case) as parameter, and you can specify a function that will get the 'invoice'.

Alternatively, you can add an extra column to the view that does not exist in your database, and fill it with an appropriate link.

```
from flask import Markup

class MyModelView(ModelView):        
    ....
    column_list = ['edit link'] + the_rest_of_columns_you_display
    column_formatters = {'edit link': lambda v, c, m, n: Markup('''
            <a href='/admin/order/edit/?invoice=%d'>Edit</a>
        ''' % m.invoice }
```

Additionally, you need to override the [edit_view function](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_admin/model/base/#BaseModelView.edit_view) so it will accept whatever parameters you need, and the respective template.